# SQL Datatype bit query

Tags: sql

Trying to find a sql query for data type bit for the following:
update the an columen to '1' where the date is <= the current date.

Can anyone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Update MyTable
Set ColumnOfTypeBit = 1
Where ColumnOfTypeDate <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Had the same query but I couldn't figure out the "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".  Thanks Mike.